# c++ simple Caesar cipher algorithm

Tags: c++, encryption, char

I am trying to make a very simple Caesar cipher algorithm to encrypt and decrypt the player's data in my game , but i am getting some weird results.The task of the algorithm is  simple, just push foward or backwards the characters in the ascii table.

```
std::string Encrypt(std::string in,int key)
{
    const char* chars=in.data();
    char* newchar=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*in.length());
    for(int c=0;c<in.length();c++)
    {
        newchar[c]=char(((int)chars[c])+key);//I suspect somewhere here is the problem
    }

    std::string out(newchar);
    return out;
}

LOGI("encrypt:%s",Encrypt("hello",10).data());
LOGI("decrypt:%s",Encrypt(Encrypt("hello",10),-10).data());
```

Output:

```
encrypt:rovvyu@ 
decrypt:hellok
```

I dont know much about encryption and i know less about how ascii and the whole character thing works in c

Comment: Is decrypting the text part of the game, if not why are you not using modern encryption techniques from established libraries? Letter substitution algorithms are not useful for any protection in today's time. Heck, people do them for fun [in the newspaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptogram).

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1`, by definition.

Comment: you should free `newchar`. `out` will make its own copy of the string.

Comment: If you are already using `std::string` why malloc the output array?

Comment: @Scott , i dont want to use any external librarie cause i want to keep it simple,and i dont real care about the users finding the real data, i just want it to make it defficult for them.

Comment: @gdii , ya i know i am just used to it and i always do this sizeof thing to be sure (i am paranoid :) )

Comment: You should get used to a safer way of handling memory. You have a leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string Encrypt(const std::string & in, int key)
{
    std::string out(in);
    for(int i=0; i < in.length(); ++i)
    {
        out[i] += key;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that adding "key" to a value in a..z may not land back in that range.  Something like

```
if (chars[c] >= 'a' && chars[c] <='z') newchar[c] = 'a' + ((chars[c]-'a'+key)%26);
else if (chars[c] >= 'A' && chars[c] <='Z') newchar[c] = 'A' + ((chars[c]-'A'+key)%26);
else newchar[c] = chars[c];
```

Hope you have a good reason for using something so weak.  BTW, use 26-key to invert.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just know how to make a Caesar cipher, cool. If you actually want to protect some data, don't do this! It is no more a cryptographic method than pig latin.

Instead, use a pre-written encryption library. Don't write your own because it takes a long time to get it right. AES is fast and good enough for most cases, and has libraries for just about every programming language.